# Is there a way to have a single sign on for both SAP Portal and .NET SharePoint Portal Site:

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, single-sign-on, windows-authentication, sap-enterprise-portal

I'm working on a SharePoint portal site, while user should be redirected to it from SAP Portal, both of the two portal, user is going to be authenticated through Active Directory.

So is there a way to have a single sign on for both of them, so user login to SAP portal and then be redirected to Sharepoint portal without providing his login credentials again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this area (and definitively not one on SAP) but if your SAP Portal and your SharePoint are set-up using the same authentication mechanism (eg : ntml or Kerberos) and you have windows authentication, this should be transparent (assuming the current user is member of any group of SharePoint that has at least a read access).

One of the client I had been working with had a similar scenario, a SAP Portal, several SharePoint site collections and share authentication across them, but there were relying on a dedicated SSO solution from Novell.

[This forum discussion](http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1771816) seems to cover a similar requirement